# string to time not working as expected

Tags: php, time

I can't figure out why this is happening but when I added -10 mins to a time... it doesn't work.

This is a simplified version:

```
$time = '08:30';

$time_minus_10m = strtotime($time) +  strtotime("-10 min");

echo '<b>'.$time.'</b> -10 mins is <b>'.date('H:i', $time_minus_10m).'</b>';
```

It outputs:

**08:30** -10 mins is **01:05**

but should output:

**08:30** -10 mins is **08:20**

Comment: Why do you expect that? The second call is calculating 10 minutes before the current time, not 10 minutes before `$time`.

Comment: I thought `strtotime("-10 min")` would give -10 mins in second...

Comment: Yes, but relative to the current time, not a time in some unrelated variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried combining them?

```
$time_minus_10m = strtotime("$time -10 minutes");
```

In isolation, `strtotime('-10 minutes')` just gives you the time 10 minutes before the current time; adding that to any other time doesn't really make sense anymore :)

If you already have an existing timestamp to anchor against, you can pass that as the second parameter to be used instead of the current time.

Comment: When I do the latter code block I get `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in`... I think this is because `$time` doesn't have a date with it.

Comment: @Arian: Yes, that's why you give the timestamp as second parameter.  Caught me as well.

Comment: @Arian Yeah, scrap that :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are subtracting 10 minutes from the current time since you don't provide the time in the `strtotime()` call.  Try:

```
$time_minus_10m = strtotime("-10 min", strtotime($time));
```

Comment: The second argument must be a timestamp, not a time string.

Comment: Doh.  Too fast and careless.

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = new DateTime('08:30');
$cloned_time = clone $time;
$time_minus_10m = $cloned_time->modify('-10 min');

echo '<b>'.$time->format('H:i').'</b> -10 mins is <b>'.$time_minus_10m->format('H:i').'</b>';
```